# Rails Postgis Nearest point

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, distance, postgis

Try to calculate nearest points in some distance and one nearest point.

in db/migrate/xxx_create_points.rb":

```
    class CreatePoints < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :points do |t|
          t.point :location, :geographic => true
          t.string :name, :null => false
          t.timestamps
        end
        change_table :points do |t|
          t.index :location, :spatial => true
        end
      end
    end
```

in config/routes.rb:

```
    get 'points/:lat/:lon/:distance', to: 'points#index', :constraints => { :lat => /[^\/]+/, :lon => /[^\/]+/}
```

in controllers/points_controller.rb:

```
    class PointsController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @points= Point.all
        if params[:distance].present? && params[:lat].present? && params[:lon].present?
          @distance = params[:distance].to_i
          @latitude = params[:lat].to_f
          @longitude = params[:lon].to_f
          @points= Point.near(@latitude, @longitude, @distance)
          @near = Point.nearest(@latitude, @longitude, 100).first
        end
    end
```

In models/point.rb:

```
    class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
      set_rgeo_factory_for_column(:location,
                                  RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(:srid => 4326))
      attr_accessible :location, :name

      scope :near, lambda { |latitude, longitude, distance|
        where("ST_Distance(location,
                           "+"'POINT(#{latitude} #{longitude})') < #{distance}")}

      scope :nearest, lambda { |latitude, longitude, distance|
        where("ST_Distance(location,
                           "+"'POINT(#{latitude} #{longitude})') < {distance}")
          .order("ST_Distance(location, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(#{latitude} #{longitude})'))").limit(1)}

    end
```

In views/points/index.html.erb:

```
    <script>
      $.each(response.data, function(i, point) {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
          'position': new google.maps.LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude), 'bounds': true });
      }
      $('#map_canvas').gmap('addShape', 'Circle', {
        ...
        'center': new google.maps.LatLng(<%= "#{@latitude},#{@longitude}" %>),
        'radius': 1 });
      $('#map_canvas').gmap('addShape', 'Circle', {
        ...
        'center': new google.maps.LatLng(<%= "#{@latitude},#{@longitude}" %>),
        'radius': <%= @distance %> });
      $('#map_canvas').gmap('addShape', 'Circle', {
        ...
        'center': new google.maps.LatLng(<%= "#{@near.location.x},#{@near.location.y}" %>),
        'radius': 2 });
    </script>
```

Result in browser: [http://xxx/points?distance=200&lat=55.7632500&lon=52.442000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAnmY.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you tied down to RGeo? If not there are other libraries that can handle all of this for you such as http://www.rubygeocoder.com/

Comment: @CWitty I have my own database of houses and streets. Geocoder in my understanding working with third-party

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostGIS always uses the coordinate axis order (X Y) or (longitude latitude). I see snippets in your code that has this reversed:

```
ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(#{latitude} #{longitude})')
```

This needs to be switched:

```
ST_MakePoint(#{longitude}, #{latitude})::geography
```

Answer (score 0):

Google maps uses mercator projections and the difference you see might be caused by the distance calculation differences between spherical projections you use in your model and mercator projections.

Try using RGeo's simple_mercator_factory in your Point class instead of using the spherical_factory.

[RGeo's documentation](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo/blob/master/lib/rgeo/geographic/interface.rb#L196) gives you more details about that.

> ```
>   # Many popular visualization technologies, such as Google and Bing
>   # maps, actually use two coordinate systems. The first is the
>   # standard WSG84 lat-long system used by the GPS and represented
>   # by EPSG 4326. Most API calls and input-output in these mapping
>   # technologies utilize this coordinate system. The second is a
>   # Mercator projection based on a "sphericalization" of the WGS84
>   # lat-long system. This projection is the basis of the map's screen
>   # and tiling coordinates, and has been assigned EPSG 3857.
> ```